# Do I need to install AzureSdk on the build server to create azure packages?

Tags: azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, packaging

We use TeamCity as our CI server (but I imagine this applies to any build server).

We have not installed the azure SDK on the build server and are able to build the projects which use the SDK using the [workaround described here](http://blog.codeassassin.com/2011/12/19/build-azure-projects-without-installing-the-azure-sdk-on-your-build-server/).

I now want the server to produce the packages for deployment to Azure, but when I run an MSBuild task to create the packages (as directed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh301088.aspx)) I get a strange error

`error MSB4057: The target "WatGetTargetFrameworkDirectories" does not exist in the project.`

which yields [few useful google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22WatGetTargetFrameworkDirectories) results.

Do I need to install the SDK?  Or is this error related to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WatGetTargetFrameworkDirectories` is a target from AzureSDKs .targets file. Looks like your error related to Azure SDK.

Except it could be more subtle error related to not very good msbuild Azure Targets. For our own azure packaging we did need to call 2 targets "Clean;CorePublish", not just "Publish". Maybe this will also help you.

Side note: why you don't want to install AzureSDK on TeamCity BuildAgent? Build agents made exactly for that - to have frameworks you need for build. Also 1.6 and 1.7 AzureSDKs can be installed side-by-side.

Comment: thanks Alexey.  One of our build servers is win 2003, which we can't install the SDK on, which is why we went with the workaround...  someone is going to install the SDK on one of the other (Win2k8) servers and we will see if that fixes the problem

Comment: gotr new server with the azure sdk on it, and voila everything worked first time.  Thanks.

Comment: Azure SDK 2.4 now requires VS 2013 Update 2.